# Angular 6 WebComponent Variables

Tags: angular, angular6, web-component

I have a properly made component that I want to do web component in angular 6. 
However, after generating the web component, the variables cease to work. 
For example, changing the value of the slider does not change the `[(ngModel)]="amountShare"`.

App.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {Injector, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {SectionComponent} from './section/section.component';
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SectionComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    entryComponents: [SectionComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    ngDoBootstrap() {
        const customSection = createCustomElement(SectionComponent, {injector: this.injector});
        customElements.define('custom-section', customSection);
    }
}
```

`section.component.ts`, `section.component.html` on [codepen](https://codepen.io/adam-skowroski/pen/mzJXmV?editors=1010)

Comment: your codepen link is broken, can you correct it please?

Comment: I correct it :)

Comment: it seems that codepen does not execute angular, can you create a working example on stackblitz please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not know stackblitz. 

I create working example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xr1nrh
And it's working!

But on my local version it's not working, I update angular on my PC. Maybe that's why it does not work with me